# copiar archivos según su nombre desde ftp

Tags: linux, oracle, ftp, jython

Por el momento tengo este codigo en **Oracle Data Integrator Studio 12c**

```
import snpsftp
import os
ftp = snpsftp.SnpsFTP('IP', 'user', 'clave')
try:
  ftp.setmode('BINARY')
  ftp.mget('/', 'EJEM*.zip', '/home')
finally:
  ftp.close()
```

El nombre del documento completo es **EJEM20180201.zip**
Ahora tengo que solo traer el archivo que se subió el mismo día.
Pero no se me ocurre una forma correcta de hacerlo, si alguien tiene alguna idea.

Comment: El código que publicas es Python?

Comment: específicamente es jython

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si te sirve la fecha del reloj interno como fecha del día podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
from datetime import date

today = str(date.today())
filename = "EJEM{}{}{}.zip".format(today[0:4], today[5:7], today[8:10])
print(filename)
```

#### El resultado:

```
EJEM20180206.zip
```

#### Tu código finalmente:

```
import snpsftp
import os
from datetime import date

ftp = snpsftp.SnpsFTP('IP', 'user', 'clave')
try:
  ftp.setmode('BINARY')
  filename = "EJEM{}{}{}.zip".format(today[0:4], today[5:7], today[8:10])
  ftp.mget('/', filename, '/home')
finally:
  ftp.close()
```

#### Explicación:

- Importamos el paquete `date` con `from datetime import date`
- Obtenemos la fecha en formato canónico `today = str(date.today())` es decir `yyyy-mm-dd`
- Hacemos un slice de `today` para obtener año, mes, día y formatear finalmente l nombre del archivo `filename = "EJEM{}{}{}.zip".format(today[0:4], today[5:7], today[8:10])`

Comment: gracias, y si la fecha interna era la que manda